# Firebase and Fabric Integration: No detectable Fabric Event in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric

I have integrated my Firebase and Fabric projects since it's available few days ago.

I have such kind of fabric events tracking configured in my code:

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Entity Click").putCustomAttribute("domain", entity.getDomain()).putCustomAttribute("entity", entity.entityId));
```

But in my Firebase console under `Analytics -> Events` and `Analytics -> StreamView`, I can't seem to see Fabric events get integrated over. All I can see is the normal generic Firebase events:

```
ad_click
ad_impression
app_clear_data
app_remove
app_update
first_open
os_update
screen_view
session_start
```

Did I misunderstand something?

**UPDATE:**

Portion of my `build.gradle` file:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

#I did not use firebase-core
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
```

**UPDATE 2:**

In Fabric Console, `Tools -> Firebase` shows the linking in green:

[image: In Fabric Console, Tools -> Firebase]

**UPDATE 3:**

I'm using the new Firebase UI. Under Spark Plan, did not currently link to Big Query.

[image: New Firebase look]

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Can you confirm which version of the Crashlytics SDK you're using?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Hey Mike, it's 2.7.1, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, even stranger then. Does your Fabric Answers linking page show any errors?

Comment: @MikeBonnell nope, looks healthy (see attached screenshot above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not really pay attention to my firebase events the past few days. But this morning I integrated my `Firebase` project over to `Google Analytics` at https://analytics.google.com in hope to gain some missing features like city/state level real-time location info. Turns out there's nothing new and it's the same info that I can find from Firebase Console. But when I check out the `Events` tab, I can now see my Fabric events. I then headed back to `Firebase Console`, and found my fabric events are showing now.

It could be the Analytics triggered the integration, or could have already populated in my Firebase prior to any of this. Either way, it's working for me now. :)